# How to show server side errors with AjaxFileUpload asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, server-side

I'm using a AjaxFileUpload control as following:

```
<ajaxtoolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="upAjaxUploader" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,jpe,jfif,png,tif,tiff,gif,bmp,dib,txt,rtf,odf,wps,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,xlsm,ods,ppt,pptx,pdf,csv,xml,xps"
                            MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" EnableViewState="true" ThrobberID="imgThrobberUpload" runat="server" Mode="Auto" />
```

On server I'm saving the file to a web service. I need to display errors within the control itself, e.g. at the place where it says "All Files Uploaded. Please select file(s) to upload."
Also, in event of an error the file should be red in colour.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to add some arguments or such?

PLEASE HELP! Thanks in advance, I'm stuck with this for past two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the ajax toolkit site](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx) you need to use the OnClientUploadError method. From the site:

> OnClientUploadError - The name of a JavaScript function executed in
>   the client-side if the file upload failed.

I'm not too sure if you can replace the "All files uploaded..." text but you'll be able to show and hide and error div / message in the JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

try to extend your 'AjaxFileUpload' with the following:

```
OnUploadedFileError="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedFileError"
```

then implement this function in the code behind:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedFileError(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    //Fired on the server side when the loaded file is corrupted
    //Display some error message here
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but the control I have is ajaxfileupload, not the asyncfileupload.